# Getting j.n.c.ClosedChannelException while running tests in Gatling Java

Tags: gatling, maven-gatling-plugin

Getting j.n.c.ClosedChannelException while running tests in Gatling Java. Please let me know what things I should try to avoid this exception.

I have tried maxConnectionsPerHost(10) and shareConnections options as well in HTTP protocol but no help.

I am running 245 req/seconds for 5 minutes. Out of 73500 requests, 37150 failing because of this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t blame the messenger. This error means your server is breaking the connection before sending the full response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it was specific to Gatling Java as I did not face the same issue when doing load testing via Karate-Gatling or K6 tool.

Comment: Your tests with other tools certainly don’t do the same thing in terms of connections, typically agressive connection pooling shared amongst virtual users.

Comment: Is there a way to change this behavior of connection pooling sharing and having independent connections per virtual user?

Comment: That’s the default behavior when you don’t use shareConnections.